# Como definir a velocidade da toggleClass (jquery)?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, jquery-toggleclass

Gostaria de definir a velocidade de animação da `toggleClass` mas não funcionou. Resolvi o problema com `CSS`:

```
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
```

Mas contudo, gostaria de saber como ficaria em `jQuery`?

Aqui esta como eu tentei :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#help").click(function() {
    $("#faq").toggleClass("col-md-10", 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id="faq">
  <p>
    Exemplo exemplo Exemplo exemplo Exemplo exemplo Exemplo exemplo Exemplo exemplo
  </p>
  <input type="button" id="help" value="change-heigth">
</div>
```

Comment: André boa tarde da uma olhada neste link talvez seja isso que procura **http://jsfiddle.net/UscQk/2/**

Answer (score 0):

Você esqueceu de adicionar no teste as classes `col-md-10` e `col-md-12`.

Além disso, é preciso adicionar também o `jquery.ui`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#help").click(function() {
    $("#faq").toggleClass("col-md-10", 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.col-md-12 {

  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  position: absolute;

}

.col-md-10 {

  line-height: 80px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
    position: absolute;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="button" id="help" value="Mudar Classe com Toogle Speed">

<div class="col-md-12" id="faq">
  <p>
    Exemplo exemplo Exemplo exemplo Exemplo exemplo Exemplo exemplo Exemplo exemplo
  </p>
  
</div>
```